# How to count rows in Lift (Scala's web framework)

Tags: scala, lift

I want to add a property to my User model that returns the number of rows in the Project table that have a user Id of the user.

So something like this...

```
def numProjects = {

    /* somehow get count from Project table
       The straight sql would be:
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM projects WHERE userId = <the current user>

     */

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb/lift-webkit/scaladocs/net/liftweb/mapper/MetaMapper.html) (found [here](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb/lift-webkit/scaladocs/)), assuming you're looking for the project count for a User of id 1234 and assuming that your Project model inherits the MetaMapper trait (probably through KeyedMetaMapper), it seems you can use the count method as such:

```
Project.count(By(User.id, 1234))
```

or

```
Project.count(BySql("userId = ?", 1234))
```

I can't test because I haven't used Lift yet, but it looks right... :) Let me know if it works!